# Fundamental solution to wave operator

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Using

$$\large \mathscr{S}_{n}(x, t) = F_{\xi}^{-1}[\tilde{\mathscr{S}_{n}}(\xi, t)] = H(t)F_{\xi}^{-1}[\frac{\sin a |\xi| t}{a |\xi|}]$$

show that the distributions

$$\large \mathscr{S}_{n}(x, t) = \frac{H(t)}{2 \pi a}(\frac{d}{\pi a^{2} dt^{2}})^{\frac{n - 3}{2}}\delta(a^{2}t^{2} - |x|^{2}) \quad n \geq 3 \text{ is odd,}$$

and

$$\large \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{2} - 1}}{2a} \pi^{-\frac{n + 1}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{n - 1}{2})\frac{H(at - |x|)}{(a^{2}t^{2} - |x|^{2})^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}} \quad n \geq 2 \text{ is even.}$$

are fundamental solutions of the wave operator $\square_{a} \mathscr{S}_{n} = \delta(x, t)$.

Here $\tilde{\mathscr{S}}(\xi, t) = H(t) \frac{\sin(a|\xi|t)}{a|\xi|}$ and $F_{x}$ is Fourier transform with respect to the variables $x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n})$ such that for any Schwartz function $\phi \in \mathscr{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n + m})$

$$\langle F_{x}[f], \phi \rangle = \langle f, F_{\xi}[\phi]$$

A fundamental solution $\mathscr{S}$ of the differential operator $L(D)$ is a distribution $\mathscr{S}$ such that

$$L(D) \mathscr{S} = \delta(x) \iff \sum_{|\alpha| = 0}^{m}a_{\alpha} D^{\alpha} \mathscr{S} = \delta(x),$$

where $L(D)$ is a linear differential operator with constant coefficients $\alpha \in C^{\infty}$ such that

$$L(D) = \sum_{|\alpha| = 0}^{m}a_{\alpha} D^{\alpha} \quad D = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}, \ldots , \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n}}).$$

I know that a tempered distribution $\mathscr{S} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is fundamental solution of the operator $L(D)$ if and only if its Fourier transform $F[\mathscr{S}]$ satisfies

$$L(-i \xi) F[\mathscr{S}] = 1,$$

where $L(\xi) = \sum_{|\alpha| = 0}^{m} a_{\alpha} \xi^{\alpha}$.

And the definition for a Fourier transform which I am using is $F[\phi](\xi) := \int \phi(x)e^{i \langle \xi, x \rangle} dx$

Edit: So I believe that I made some progress. On the case $n = 3$ the book has the following formula for a simple layer $\delta_{S_{R}}$ on the spherical surface $S_{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ given by

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F[\delta_{S_{R}}] &= \langle \delta_{S_{R}}(x), \eta(x)e^{i \langle \xi, x \rangle} \rangle \\
& = \int_{S_{R}} \eta(x)e^{\langle \xi, x \rangle} dS_{x} \\
& = R^{2} \int_{S} e^{i R\langle \xi, x \rangle} dS \\
& = R^{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{i R |\xi| \cos(\theta)}\sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi \\
& = 4 \pi R \frac{\sin R |\xi|}{|\xi|}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

So using this we deduce

$$F_{\xi}^{-1}[\frac{\sin a |\xi| t}{a |\xi|}] = \frac{1}{4 \pi a t} \delta_{S_{at}}(x).$$

And hence

$$\mathscr{S}_{3}(x, t) = \frac{H(t)}{4 \pi a^{2}t}\delta_{S_{at}}(x) = \frac{H(t)}{2 \pi at} \delta(a^{2}t^{2} - |x|^{2}).$$

And this is case $n = 3$, if we substitute $n = 3$ in the problem statement above. So it seems that for the case $n \geq 3$ odd we need to solve $F_{\xi}^{-1}[\frac{\sin a |\xi| t}{a |\xi|}]$ and in particular show it is equal to

$$F_{\xi}^{-1}[\frac{\sin a |\xi| t}{a |\xi|}] = \frac{1}{2 \pi a}(\frac{d}{\pi a^{2} dt^{2}})^{\frac{n - 3}{2}}\delta(a^{2}t^{2} - |x|^{2}).$$

Comment: If you read French, you can see Chapter 5.2 from page 40 onward here: https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~nonnenma/enseign/PbEvol_Fourier_2015_PG.pdf

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski I don't read French. Do you have a source in English, Hungarian, Romanian, or German? I might try and see if I understand the notes in French you gave.

Comment: Sorry if I am of not much help, but you can find the resources for the course at the bottom of the page (Bibliographie relative à ce cours): https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~nonnenma/enseign/Enseignement.html

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski So I looked at the notes and I understood some amount. The topic on the wave equation starts with p. 38. However, I could not find the explicit part where the fundamental solution to the wave operator is shown. However, starting with p. 44 the method of d'Hughens is explained and in particular the method of descent starting with p. 48 is explained for the odd case. But even still I cannot seem to solve it. I will take a look at the bibliography. Thanks for the help.